# Locating Sweden's Net Savings Rate, Public Saving, Private Saving, and Corporate Savings Rates?

Tags: saving

I'm looking at the savings rates for Sweden and would first like to better understand the breakdown between Gross National Savings, and Net Savings? I've looked around and still haven't found an explanation which clarifies this.

Secondly, from a purely data gathering perspective, I've checked the OECD, World Bank, IMF, Bloomberg etc, but I am unable so far to identify the Household, Private, and Public savings rates (which I think in total sum to the Net or Gross Savings rate?)

Comment: Try http://www.statistikdatabasen.scb.se/pxweb/en/ssd/START__NR__NR0103__NR0103F/SektorENS2010Ar/?rxid=518bd6ff-bf96-4678-ace5-86f752ae1ff8 for some data

Comment: Still unable to locate the data